# Angular js, listing file names from a local folder

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a folder that has a list of images in my 'www' folder.

I want to be able to just list then names of the files only. How would I do that?

Comment: What webserver do you use?

Comment: I am using IIS, but the folder isn't in my server, its in the same www root folder